# Not getting output after executing the python program

Tags: python-3.x, output

I am learing Python so need help in initial steps. Please guide.

I wrote a Simple Program :

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self,name,salary,age):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age

x=Employee('Aman','900000','27')

print(x.name)
print(x.salary)
print(x.age)
```

It is showing no error but also not printing anything

Comment: Your code is working for me. But the initial post you have done had some alignments problem. Is that the code that you are trying?

Comment: Pls check indentation and minors things like that, your code is fine.

Comment: As the formatting was edited by someone else, please confirm that how the code looks in your question now is actually how it is formatted in your own code.

Comment: How are you executing your code?  Command line?  IDE?  Suspect it's not your code but the way you're trying to run it.